# grep with multiple $

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I am grepping some php code files for an array variable and I ran into an issue which I am curious to understand.

I attempted to grep:

```
grep -RF "$array_variable['some_key'][$key_variable]" *
```

and it returned nothing. However, if I escape the second dollar sign, it then finds lines with that pattern.

```
grep -RF "$array_variable['some_key'][\$key_variable]" *
```

The -F flag from the man page says it treats the pattern as a fixed string and not a regex. It seems to handle the first dollar sign only.

Please help me understand how grep is interpreting this command. Could this be a shell issue rather than a regex issue?

**UPDATE** Added an additional array layer, which shows why I don't want to use single quotes. It's more work to escape the single quotes than the dollar sign.

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: I think first $ is being taken as a "start of line" anchor instead of a  literal $.

Comment: What did you intend `"$array_variable['some_key'][$key_variable]"` to mean? [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input (including the values of any variables) and expected output and then someone will be able to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use single quotes instead of double quotes. Double quotes let shell expand variable names starting with `$`:

```
grep -RF '$array_variable[$key_variable]' .
```

---

For your **edited question**, you can use escaped `$` within double quotes:

```
grep -RF "\$array_variable['some_key'][\$key_variable]" .
```

Comment: Also, the shell is not expanding the $array_variable variable

Comment: Shell expands `$array_variable` as well and it expands to an empty string. But with escaped 2nd `$` it effectively becomes `grep -RF '[$key_variable]' .` and you get the result. When both variables expand then it effectively becomes `grep -RF '[]' .` and nothing is found.

Answer (score 0):

I think you intend to search for occurrences of some array variable with two subindices values and you don't know that the square brackets are special for grep, meaning a class of characters.  If you want to substitute the `${array_variable}` name and `${key_variable}` values into the grep expressión, you had better to use complete syntax as I have done, but the most important thing is that if you want to match literally the `[` and `]` brackets, you need to escape them.  As in

```
grep -RF "${array_variable}\['some_key']\[${key_variable}]"
```

(only the left square bracket is needed to be escaped)
In that case, if you have, for example `foo` stored in `array_variable` and `bar` in variable `key_variable`, the actual grep command will be

```
greep -RF "foo\['some_key']\[bar]"
```

withoug the escaping to the brackets, the regexp will search for occurences of foo, followed by one of `'somk_y` and followed by one of `bar`, like `foo'r`, or `foo__`, but nothing similar to an array variable with its subindices.